# Curvilinear integral (Stokes formula)

Tags: integration, stokes-theorem

How can I solve this integral with help Stokes formula:

$$\oint_L (y-z)\,dx + (z-x)\,dy + (x-y)\,dz,$$

where $L$ is the circle: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2,\; y=x\tan(\varphi),\; \varphi \in \left(0, \pi \right)$ 
oriented negatively with respect to the vector $(1, 0, 0).$

I think $y=x\tan(\varphi)$ cuts off a circle with radius $1$ and center in $(0,0)$ point from the sphere. But then I am stuck, because I don't know what surface I need. Maybe hemisphere or any plane with any tilt angle.

Sorry, if this task a very simple, but only today I got acquainted with this formula.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a circle:

$ L = \begin{cases} x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2\\
                    y = xtan(\phi) 
       \end{cases} $
where $ \phi \in (0, \pi)$

Our integral transform in surface integral by the Stokes formula:

$ \iint_{S} det\begin{pmatrix}
cos\alpha & cos\beta & cos\gamma\\
\frac{\partial }{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
P & Q & R
\end{pmatrix} = -2(cos\alpha + cos\beta + cos\gamma)\cdot mes\left| {S} \right| = -2\pi r^2(cos\alpha + cos\beta + cos\gamma) $

Cosines uphere is const, because $ S = \begin{cases} x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq R^2\\
                    y = xtan(\phi) 
       \end{cases} $
where $ \phi \in (0, \pi)$, is a plane.

Find a normal vector to determine the cosines.

$\overline {\nu} = \pm \frac{(A, B, C)}{\sqrt {A^2 + B^2 + C^2}} = \pm \frac{(1-tan\phi, 1, 0)}{\sqrt {(tan\phi)^2 + 1}} = \pm (-\frac{sin\phi\left| {cos\phi} \right|}{cos\phi}, \left| {cos\phi} \right|, 0) = \pm (-sin\phi sgn(cos\phi), \left| {cos\phi} \right|, 0) $

Then for $\phi \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ we have the answer: $ 2\sqrt{2} \cdot sin(\frac{\pi}{4} - \phi) \pi R^2 $

But for $ \phi \in (\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi)$ a little harder. There are a normal vectors change a direction. Consequently we have our answer finally:

$ \oint_L (y-z)\,dx + (z-x)\,dy + (x-y)\,dz $ = $ 2\sqrt{2} \cdot sin(\frac{\pi}{4} - \phi) \pi R^2 $

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a simple parametrization: $${\bf r}(t) = (\cos t, \sin t, -1+\cos t), \quad 0 \leq t< 2\pi,$$ and all the functions involved ar straighforward to manipulate.

Writing ${\rm d}x = -\sin t\,{\rm d}t$ then allows you to substitute and compute. .

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try it. But after I use Stokes formula I need to compute surface integral and on this point I don't know what kind of surface I need.